# Adding new option for command line parser: Unrecognised option error

Tags: java, command-line

So I've forked and zipped some code from a github repository that contains java files which require command line arguments.

Here's the relevant code for my problem-

```
Options options = new Options();
    options.addOption("f", false, "force processing of text file");
    options.addOption("printHTML", false, "print HTML file for inspection");
    options.addOption("w", true, "coreference weight file");
    options.addOption("doc", true, "text document to process");
    options.addOption("tok", true, "processed text document");
    options.addOption("docId", true, "text document ID to process");
    options.addOption("p", true, "output directory");
    options.addOption("id", true, "book ID");
    options.addOption("d", false, "dump pronoun and quotes for annotation")

    CommandLine cmd = null;
    try {
        CommandLineParser parser = new BasicParser();
        cmd = parser.parse(options, args);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

To which I added an extra option 'quoteAttr' as per my own requirements

```
Options options = new Options();
    options.addOption("f", false, "force processing of text file");
    options.addOption("printHTML", false, "print HTML file for inspection");
    options.addOption("quoteAttr", false, "print quote ids and their attributions");//Here
    options.addOption("w", true, "coreference weight file");
    options.addOption("doc", true, "text document to process");
    options.addOption("tok", true, "processed text document");
    options.addOption("docId", true, "text document ID to process");
    options.addOption("p", true, "output directory");
    options.addOption("id", true, "book ID");
    options.addOption("d", false, "dump pronoun and quotes for annotation");

    CommandLine cmd = null;
    try {
        CommandLineParser parser = new BasicParser();
        cmd = parser.parse(options, args);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Adding this option to the code in itself does nothing to regular functioning of the program.

As shown here -

```
./runjava novels/BookNLP -doc data/originalTexts/dickens.oliver.pg730.txt -printHTML -p data/output/dickens -tok data/tokens/dickens.oliver.tokens -f
Adding annotator tokenize
Adding annotator ssplit
Adding annotator pos
Reading POS tagger model from edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger ... done [1.6 sec].
Adding annotator lemma
Adding annotator ner
Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... done [4.6 sec].
Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ...
```

However when I use the 'quoteAttr' option on the command line -

```
./runjava novels/BookNLP -doc data/originalTexts/dickens.oliver.pg730.txt -printHTML -quoteAttr -p data/output/dickens -tok data/tokens/dickens.oliver.tokens -f
```

I get this error -

```
org.apache.commons.cli.UnrecognizedOptionException: Unrecognized option: -quoteAttr
at org.apache.commons.cli.Parser.processOption(Parser.java:363)
at org.apache.commons.cli.Parser.parse(Parser.java:199)
at org.apache.commons.cli.Parser.parse(Parser.java:85)
at novels.BookNLP.main(BookNLP.java:98)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at novels.BookNLP.main(BookNLP.java:106)
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you sure that you have rebuild your project before testing?

Comment: It seems that it was "able" to parse your option, since it prints it out, but there is not a Class or some logic that is registered to be executed. Probably somewhere there is a huge "Select case" or equivalent factory which returns the logic to be executed. Search for the string "Unrecognized" and see where it is not finding the new option

Comment: And instead of the `BasicParser` I would use `new DefaultParser()` because the `BasicParser` is deprecated.

Comment: @KevinWallis No I did not do that ... I just directly ran the command after the changes I made. I guess that is the source of the problem. The github page says I need to use 'ant' if I want to compile everything...

Comment: @KevinWallis I tried DefaultParser too

Comment: @NikhilPrabhu yeah then use `ant` do they have the `ant` in the repo?

Comment: Nope, Installing it now. Thanks for the help though!